# CMD: How do I recursively remove the "Hidden"-Attribute of files and directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I can't find a command or simple batch of commands to recursively remove the "Hidden"-Attribute from files and directories. All commands like "attrib" and "for" seem to skip hidden files. E.g.:

```
attrib -H /S /D /L mydir
```

doesn't do anything at all, because it skips all hidden stuff. Does someone know how to do this with standard Windows tools?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the -h and specify that mydir is a directory

```
attrib /S /D /L -H mydir\*.*
```

Comment: I hesitated on this answer because it doesn't remove the "Hidden"-Flag of "mydir". But no other solution seem to come up. The hint about adding the "*.*" and then adding an additional command "attrib -H /D /L mydir" solved my problem, so I'll gratefully accept this answer. P.S.: For me it didn't matter where I put the -h.

Answer (score 40):

You can't remove hidden without also removing system.

You want:

```
cd mydir
attrib -H -S /D /S
```

That will remove the hidden and system attributes from all the files/folders inside of your current directory.

Comment: do we need capitalized H, S, D, S letters? I test on Windows 10 and see no difference between upper and lower letters

Comment: The official documentation show lower case letters and no upper case letters, so no, it is not case-sensitive.
See these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000797.htm

Answer (score 7):

if you wanna remove attributes for all files in all folders on whole flash drive do this:

**attrib -r -s -h /S /D**

this command will remove attrubutes for all files folders and subfolders:

-read only
-system file
-is hidden
-Processes matching files and all subfolders.
-Processes folders as well

Answer (score 3):

To launch command prompt in administrator mode

1. Type *cmd* in Search and hold <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to open in **administrator** mode
2. Type `attrib -h -r -s /s /d "location of the drive letter:" \*.*`

Comment: "Search" doesn't exist in all windows versions, and "Ctrl+Shift" does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To make a batch file for its current directory and sub directories:

```
cd %~dp0
attrib -h -r -s /s /d /l *.*
```

Answer (score 0):

just type

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d j:*.*
```

where j is the drive letter..*.* unlocks all the locked stuff in j drive

if u want to make it specific..then go to a specific location using cmd and then type

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d "foldername"
```

it can also be used to lock drives or folders just alter "-" with "+"

```
attrib +h +r +s /s /d "foldername"
```

Answer (score 0):

For example folder named new under **E:** drive

type the command:

```
e:\cd new

e:\new\attrib *.* -s -h /s /d
```

and all the files and folders are un-hidden